# Is CodeIgniter a component-based PHP framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Yii framework specifies that it was a component-based PHP framework and i need to know whether CodeIgniter was a component-based PHP framework or not?

In my search i found that CodeIgniter was a OO PHP framework. Is both the same, the Object oriented and Component based? and also whether CI a component-based PHP framework?

Comment: Can you define "component-based"?

Comment: "Yii framework specifies that it was a component-based PHP framework" --- it's a home brew term. They just assumed it would be cool to say so and said that.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar: "OOP based" is a weird phrase as well.

Comment: @RohanKumar CakePHP component based.?? are you sure, i saw somewhere that it was not

Comment: CI is not component based, at least in my interpretation of the term; I think as Zend as the most component-based, and symphony to a lesser extent.

Comment: CI is not even Object Oriented since it breaks most of the [OOP principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Comment: CI is OOP based framework and I agree with @Touki too.

Comment: @NiloySaha what you are saying? OOp based and not OOP based.?

Comment: Its OOP based but you are free to break the rules, its loosely based and not as structured as `ZEND` or `CakePHP` I think. @SobinAugustine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CodeIgniter is not a component based framework.**
A component based framework is also called a pull based framework, CodeIgniter is a push based framework.

### Think of component based as one way to organize car parts in a garage.

In a component based garage you would have all your tires in one area, and all the suspension parts in another area, and the transmission parts elsewhere etc.

But then a different garage that was an object oriented type garage structure would have different sections in your garage for each type of car. So all your chrysler parts would be in one section; you could get tires there and the suspension parts and transmission parts specific to that model all in one location. Then the different section in that same oo garage would have all your mercedes parts; the tires, suspension, and tranny. This garage is based on the fact that all the cars have the same parts, and kept organized according to each specific object (a.k.a manufacturer).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework

Answer (score 2):

**Object oriented** and **Component** based are completely different terms.

### Object Oriented Framework:

Object Oriented frameworks are one step ahead as they reuse designs for specific problems. An object framework is a collection of cooperating objects that provide an integrated solution within an application or technology.

### Component based Framework

A component framework defines rules for independently developed and dynamically loadable components, rather than for classes that are linked together. They require a whole new set of methodologies for software modeling, design, development, and implementation, and will change the ways software are developed and reused.

Comment: and CI component based or not ?